# What does auditd log by default (i.e. when no rules are defined?)

Tags: security, debian, debian-jessie, auditd

I installed `auditd` and `audispd-plugins` on my Debian Jessie machine and didn't touch any configuration. I see events being written to `/var/log/audit/audit.log`, for example:

```
type=LOGIN msg=audit(1462384141.770:838): pid=3662 uid=0 old-auid=4294967295 auid=0 old-ses=4294967295 ses=21 res=1
type=USER_START msg=audit(1462384141.770:839): pid=3662 uid=0 auid=0 ses=21 msg='op=PAM:session_open acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
type=CRED_DISP msg=audit(1462384141.778:840): pid=3662 uid=0 auid=0 ses=21 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
type=USER_END msg=audit(1462384141.778:841): pid=3662 uid=0 auid=0 ses=21 msg='op=PAM:session_close acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
type=USER_ACCT msg=audit(1462384201.780:842): pid=3761 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:accounting acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
type=CRED_ACQ msg=audit(1462384201.780:843): pid=3761 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
type=LOGIN msg=audit(1462384201.780:844): pid=3761 uid=0 old-auid=4294967295 auid=0 old-ses=4294967295 ses=22 res=1
type=USER_START msg=audit(1462384201.780:845): pid=3761 uid=0 auid=0 ses=22 msg='op=PAM:session_open acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
type=CRED_DISP msg=audit(1462384201.796:846): pid=3761 uid=0 auid=0 ses=22 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
type=USER_END msg=audit(1462384201.800:847): pid=3761 uid=0 auid=0 ses=22 msg='op=PAM:session_close acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/cron" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
```

But I'm not sure why I'm seeing anything in the log in the first place, because I have no rules defined:

```
$ auditctl -l
No rules
```

I can't find any rules in `/etc/audit/audit.rules` or `/etc/audit/rules.d` except for the defaults:

```
-D
-b 320
```

Obviously I'm missing something. What is getting logged by default?

Answer (score 7):

These events are coming from other capability (pam, openssh, etc) that send audit events to the auditing service. If you don't want any events, add audit=0 to the kernel command line args.

If you want to know what capability that may want to use the auditing service try something like

```
[burn@fc24 ~]$ rpm -q --whatrequires audit-libs
libsemanage-2.5-2.fc24.x86_64
shadow-utils-4.2.1-8.fc24.x86_64
pam-1.2.1-5.fc24.x86_64
util-linux-2.28-3.fc24.x86_64
openssh-7.2p2-9.fc24.x86_64
passwd-0.79-8.fc24.x86_64
gdm-3.20.1-3.fc24.x86_64
pam-1.2.1-5.fc24.i686
[burn@fc24 ~]$
```

Answer (score 4):

By default, auditd logs security-related commands. This is not something that can be seen in the config files, it happens by default when auditd is running. You can get a summary of what commands have been logged on your system recently using:

```
sudo aureport -x --summary
```

I have been unable to find a list of all the commands that are logged by default. My CentOS 7 system logs these by default (not an exhaustive list, just what's shown in the logs):

```
/usr/sbin/crond
/usr/libexec/dovecot/auth
/usr/sbin/sshd
/usr/bin/sudo
/usr/sbin/xtables-multi
/usr/lib/systemd/systemd
/usr/bin/passwd
```

It also logs log-ins, log-outs and SELinux-related messages.

Two articles that were used for reference:

- [How To Use the Linux Auditing System on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-linux-auditing-system-on-centos-7)
- [How To Write Custom System Audit Rules on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-write-custom-system-audit-rules-on-centos-7)

Comment: Is it possible to suppress some of these? I'm tracking an actual issue, but one remote monitoring plugin uses an ssh connection every few minutes that clutters up the logs something fierce.

Comment: The best thing to look at is probably the remote monitoring plugin, see if you can stop it from logging. Or filter the logs to get only what you want.