# suppress audit events from a specific user

Tags: linux, auditd

I'm trying to track down the source cause of a breakin on a serverhosting customer's website.

`auditd` is a great help in showing me what directory to look in when yet another bit of malware (the site is something of a *mess*, but not mine to clear up even if I wanted to) activates and screws up the site, but the audit logs are tricky to read because it also logs the ssh activity from a monitoring script that connects every two minutes to check various statuses, as well as another monitoring system that's triggered by cron.

I've made several attempts in auditctl to tell it to stop  reporting these:

```
root@zelia:/var/log/audit# auditctl -l 
-a never,user -F auid=116
-a never,task -F auid=116
-a never,exit -S all -F auid=116
-a never,exit -S all -F uid=116
```

(UID 116, user 'meminfo' is the one I want to suppress)

However, every few minutes I still get the following:

```
type=USER_ACCT msg=audit(1491386883.189:462708): pid=1502 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:accounting acct="meminfo" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=prtg.systemec.nl addr=89.20.80.149 terminal=ssh res=success'
type=CRED_ACQ msg=audit(1491386883.189:462709): pid=1502 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="meminfo" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=monitor.company.internal addr=89.20.80.149 terminal=ssh res=success'
type=LOGIN msg=audit(1491386883.189:462710): pid=1502 uid=0 old-auid=4294967295 auid=116 old-ses=4294967295 ses=368164 res=1
type=USER_ACCT msg=audit(1491386883.197:462711): pid=1504 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:accounting acct="meminfo" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
type=USER_START msg=audit(1491386883.197:462712): pid=1504 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:session_open acct="meminfo" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1491386883.213:462713): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg=' comm="user@116" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
type=SERVICE_STOP msg=audit(1491386883.365:462714): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg=' comm="user@116" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
```

As a result, audit logs keep filling up and I'm missing important backlog.

On the other hand, while I don't *think* the breakin is happening via SSH, a log of who logs onto the server when may be useful to have handy.

Obviously, the rules I attempted to add to keep `meminfo` suppressed don't work correctly. What am I doing wrong?

**ADDENDUM** For some reason, adding `auditctl -a never,task` afterwards causes the `never,task` rule to be loaded first and *everything* gets suppressed, including what I really did want to see.

**ADDENDUM #2** As explained in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/774862/what-does-auditd-log-by-default-i-e-when-no-rules-are-defined), the messages I'm trying to suppress are generated by default by the PAM subsystems and not by additional rules in `audit.rules`, so that's an additional problem...

Answer (score 4):

In your logfile, `uid=0` on these lines means these processes are started by the `root`, not `meminfo`.

> `auid=500`
>
> The auid field records the Audit user ID, that is the loginuid. This
>   ID is assigned to a user upon login and is inherited by every process
>   even when the user's identity changes (for example, by switching user
>   accounts with the `su - john` command).
>
> `uid=500`
>
> The uid field records the user ID of the user who started the analyzed
>   process. The user ID can be interpreted into user names with the
>   following command: `ausearch -i --uid UID`. In this case, `500` is the
>   user ID of user `shadowman`.

This may be caused by running the program from `root` users `crontab` or if the process invokes a service that must be first started as `root` (with `setuid`) to enable it to use *privileged ports* `<1024`.

Probably you do not want to suppress all `auid=0` activity as it would suppress something meaningful.

If your `auditd` can filter by process name i.e. `exe=`, like [RHEL7 since BZ#1135562](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/7.3_Release_Notes/new_features_security.html), suppressing `sshd` started by `root` should be safe IF you also have `PermitRootLogin no`:

```
auditctl
    -a never,user -F auid=0 -F exe="/usr/sbin/sshd"
    -a never,task -F auid=0 -F exe="/usr/sbin/sshd"
```

However, in most cases `-F` is limited to fields outside `msg=' '` and only has operators that won't allow regular expressions: `-F [n=v | n!=v | n<v | n>v | n<=v | n>=v | n&v | n&=v]`.

---

One option is to increase the `max_log_file` or `num_logs` to keep more history, if the log size is not a problem. **You don't have to read the log format directly**, as you have [`aureport`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/aureport) and [`ausearch`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ausearch).

Comment: That explains, yes. Unfortunately, I was kind of hoping to be able to differentiate between ssh sessions for user meminfo (suppress) and ssh sessions for everyone else (log). But if that's not in the cards... I'll see what works. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the version of auditd in debian Jessie does not include `exe=` as a possible field.

Comment: It may only be available in RHEL 7. It would be so nice and easy to be able to filter by `exe= `, `comm= ` and `acct= `. You could send a letter to [Santa](https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-kernel/blob/master/MAINTAINERS#L2300).

Comment: @Shadur thank you for saving me more hours of troubleshooting something that doesn't work on debian.